# Cocos2d-x c++ - Wait for action finish before continuing

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, action

I'm making a slider puzzle, this function should move a tile and then return back to the main function so that i can continue playing, i also use this function to shuffle the tiles at the beginning of the game but when i call this all the tiles move toghether and go in the wrong spot or off the screen, this is because instead of running the action moveTo which takes 0.2 sec and then, after 0.2 sec, returning, it starts the action and returns straight away so when this gets called again the tile is still moving messing everything up.

is there any way to stop the code from continuing before the action has finished? thanks ;)

```
bool GameScene::updateTile(Sprite* tile, int newPos)
{
    auto moveTo = MoveTo::create(0.2, Vec2(widthArray[newPos], heightArray[newPos]));
    auto whatever = CallFunc::create([]() {
        CCLOG("hi");
    });
    auto seq = Sequence::create(moveTo, whatever, nullptr);
    tile->runAction(seq);
    CCLOG("running");
    return true;
}
```

//edit

This code prints: 
"running"
and after 0.2 sec (time it takes to run action moveTo)
"hi" (from action whatever)

my goal is for it to wait 0.2 sec then print "hi" and, only after that, print "running" but if i try to stop the code using any kind of delay or loop
like:

```
 bool GameScene::updateTile(Sprite* tile, int newPos)
    {
        auto moveTo = MoveTo::create(0.2, Vec2(widthArray[newPos], heightArray[newPos]));
        auto whatever = CallFunc::create([]() {
            CCLOG("hi");
        });
        auto seq = Sequence::create(moveTo, whatever, nullptr);
        tile->runAction(seq);
        while (tile->getNumberOfRunningActions != 0)
              { //delay 
              }
        CCLOG("running");
        return true;
    }
```

it does not run any action and just gets stuck, any ideas?

Comment: Cocos2d-x is single thread. A while loop will make it stucked. Use a scheduled function instead of while-loop. See my edit2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tag` to check whether an action has finished:

```
bool GameScene::updateTile(Sprite* tile, int newPos)
{
    static const int MY_MOVE_SEQ = 3333;
    if (tile->getActionByTag(MY_MOVE_SEQ) && !tile->getActionByTag(MY_MOVE_SEQ)->isDone()) {
        return;
        //or you can stop the last action sequence and then run new action
        //tile->stopActionByTag(MY_MOVE_SEQ);
    }

    auto moveTo = MoveTo::create(0.2, Vec2(widthArray[newPos], heightArray[newPos]));
    auto whatever = CallFunc::create([]() {
        CCLOG("hi");
    });
    auto seq = Sequence::create(moveTo, whatever, nullptr);
    //set tag here!
    seq->setTag(MY_MOVE_SEQ);

    tile->runAction(seq);
    CCLOG("running");
    return true;
}
```

//Edit

```
    bool anyActionRunning = false;
    tile->getParent()->enumerateChildren("//Tile", [&anyActionRunning](Node* child) {
        if (child->getActionByTag(MY_MOVE_SEQ) && !child->getActionByTag(MY_MOVE_SEQ)->isDone()) {
            anyActionRunning = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

//Edit2:

```
static const string funcName = "CheckAction";
tile->schedule([tile](float dt) {
    if (tile->getNumberOfRunningActions == 0) {
        CCLOG("running");
        tile->unschedule(funcName);
    }
}, funcName);
```

Comment: Hi, with this i can stop the current tile from doing another action and they don't go off the screen anymore, but what i would like it to do is to wait after running the sequence for all the actions to finish before doing CCLOG("running"); and continuing in the code

Comment: Not really understand your question. But I guess you can use `enumerateChildren` and timers to do it.@Gualtiero

Comment: ok, i edited the question to make it clearer, the problem is that this code prints :
running
and after 0.2 sec(time it takes to run action moveTo)
hi(from action whatever)

my goal is for it to wait 0.2 sec then print hi and, only after that, print running but if i try to stop the code using any kind of delay or loop it does not run any action and just gets stuck, any ideas ?

Comment: @Zen I'm new to cocos2dx and trying to do the same thing but can you tell me what function is passed to `tile->unschedule`? It's a little confusing in the above example.

Comment: No function (pointer) is passed to `unschedule`. Rather, we pass function name (a string) to `unschedule` since cocos-2dx use strings to identify callback functions. @akash93